# Feedback loop in OpenModelica

Tags: simulation, modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica

I am currently working on a two zone combustion model in OpenModelica and I want to simulate the loop presented in the next picture [volume calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQuKM.png). With this way OpenModelica always gives me singular matrix error. Is it even possible to this kind of stuff with Modelica Media library?

Comment: It seems likely that it can be modelled in Modelica, but others cannot answer what's wrong without seeing the model code of your approach.